# Merge multiple rows to 1 XML node instead of repeating nodes with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am currently working on creating XML output via SQL Server for a 3rd party application using T-SQL. A few nodes are repeating based on the number of rows in the source data. I want these nodes to only present themselves once at the top of the beginning of the data regardless of the number of rows. I have added some data to explain what is needed.

```
CREATE TABLE  #XML
( 
 party_id NVARCHAR(8)
,data_timestamp datetime
,questiontype nvarchar(10)
,legalbasis nvarchar(10)
,active_customer bit
,code  NVARCHAR(30)
,[description] NVARCHAR(20)
,date_of_birth date
,initials_np NVARCHAR(20)
,first_name NVARCHAR(20)
,last_name NVARCHAR(20)
,address_type NVARCHAR(20)
,address NVARCHAR(40)
,city NVARCHAR(10)
 )
 INSERT INTO #XML
 (
  party_id 
,data_timestamp 
,questiontype
,legalbasis
,active_customer
,code  
,[description] 
,date_of_birth 
,initials_np 
,first_name 
,last_name 
,address_type 
,address 
,city 

 )
 Values('CUST1',GETDATE(),'Customer','legal01',1,'Customer Found','Valid', '11/05/1979', 'JBS','John','Smith','Primary Address','5 Cod street', 'Amsterdam')
 ,('CUST1',GETDATE(),'Customer','legal01',1,'Customer Found','Valid', '11/05/1979', 'JBS','John','Smith','Secondary Address','4 Pike street', 'Rotterdam')
 ,('CUST2',GETDATE(),'Customer','legal01',0,'Customer not Found',NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL)
```

The query I am using is

```
SELECT 
data_timestamp as 'Metadata/data_timestamp'
    ,questiontype as 'Metadata/questiontype'
    ,legalbasis   as  'Metadata/legalbasis'
,code as 'notification/code'
,[description] as   'notification/description'
,date_of_birth as 'register/natural_person/date_of_birth'
,initials_np as 'register/natural_person/name/Initials'
,first_name as   'register/natural_person/name/first_name'
,last_name as  'register/natural_person/name/last_name'
 ,(   SELECT 
            B.city , B.address_type ,
            B.address
            FROM  #XML AS B
            WHERE B.party_id = T.party_id
                FOR XML PATH ('address'), TYPE
            ) 
FROM #XML T
 group by   party_id  ,data_timestamp  ,active_customer ,code   ,[description]  ,date_of_birth  ,initials_np  ,first_name  ,last_name
   ,questiontype ,legalbasis

FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('bdrp_client_response'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

This produces the following

```
<bdrp_client_response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Metadata>
    <data_timestamp>2022-10-18T22:44:31.727</data_timestamp>
    <questiontype>Customer</questiontype>
    <legalbasis>legal01</legalbasis>
  </Metadata>
  <notification>
    <code>Customer Found</code>
    <description>Valid</description>
  </notification>
  <register>
    <natural_person>
      <date_of_birth>1979-11-05</date_of_birth>
      <name>
        <Initials>JBS</Initials>
        <first_name>John</first_name>
        <last_name>Smith</last_name>
      </name>
    </natural_person>
  </register>
  <address>
    <city>Amsterdam</city>
    <address_type>Primary Address</address_type>
    <address>5 Cod street</address>
  </address>
  <address>
    <city>Rotterdam</city>
    <address_type>Secondary Address</address_type>
    <address>4 Pike street</address>
  </address>
  <Metadata>
    <data_timestamp>2022-10-18T22:44:31.727</data_timestamp>
    <questiontype>Customer</questiontype>
    <legalbasis>legal01</legalbasis>
  </Metadata>
  <notification>
    <code>Customer not Found</code>
    <description xsi:nil="true" />
  </notification>
  <register>
    <natural_person>
      <date_of_birth xsi:nil="true" />
      <name>
        <Initials xsi:nil="true" />
        <first_name xsi:nil="true" />
        <last_name xsi:nil="true" />
      </name>
    </natural_person>
  </register>
  <address />
</bdrp_client_response>
```

As there are 3 rows in the source I am seeing the metadata nodes 3 times. I only want them once at the top of the XML and no more. The output should look like this:

```
<bdrp_client_response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <notification>
    <code>Customer Found</code>
    <description>Valid</description>
  </notification>
  <register>
    <natural_person>
      <date_of_birth>1979-11-05</date_of_birth>
      <name>
        <Initials>JBS</Initials>
        <first_name>John</first_name>
        <last_name>Smith</last_name>
      </name>
    </natural_person>
  </register>
  <address>
    <city>Amsterdam</city>
    <address_type>Primary Address</address_type>
    <address>5 Cod street</address>
  </address>
  <address>
    <city>Rotterdam</city>
    <address_type>Secondary Address</address_type>
    <address>4 Pike street</address>
  </address>
  <notification>
    <code>Customer not Found</code>
    <description xsi:nil="true" />
  </notification>
  <register>
    <natural_person>
      <date_of_birth xsi:nil="true" />
      <name>
        <Initials xsi:nil="true" />
        <first_name xsi:nil="true" />
        <last_name xsi:nil="true" />
      </name>
    </natural_person>
  </register>
  <address />
</bdrp_client_response>
```

Comment: _"I am seeing the metadata nodes 3 times"_ - I see only two.  _"I only want them once at the top of the XML and no more. The output should look like this"_ - There is no metadata node in the output you show. Please make the examples consistent with the question.

Comment: `select case row_number() over(order by @@spid) when 1 then 
  (select T.data_timestamp as 'Metadata/data_timestamp',
  T.questiontype as 'Metadata/questiontype',
  T.legalbasis as  'Metadata/legalbasis'
    for xml path(''), type) end
,code as 'notification/code'…`

Comment: @lptr I forgot to add a comment. This is precisely what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: ..@EseosaOmoregie …. 

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
    data_timestamp as 'data_timestamp'
        ,questiontype as 'questiontype'
        ,legalbasis   as  'legalbasis'
    ,code as 'notification/code'
    ,[description] as   'notification/description'
    ,date_of_birth as 'register/natural_person/date_of_birth'
    ,initials_np as 'register/natural_person/name/Initials'
    ,first_name as   'register/natural_person/name/first_name'
    ,last_name as  'register/natural_person/name/last_name'
     ,(   SELECT 
                B.city , B.address_type ,
                B.address
                FROM  #XML AS B
                WHERE B.party_id = T.party_id
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                ) as 'address'
    FROM #XML T
     group by   party_id  ,data_timestamp  ,active_customer ,code   ,[description]  ,date_of_birth  ,initials_np  ,first_name  ,last_name
       ,questiontype ,legalbasis

    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) 
FOR XML PATH('Metadata'),ROOT('bdrp_client_response'), ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).